# Controlling number of decimal digits in print output in R

Tags: r, precision, digits, r-faq, output-formatting

There is an option in R to get control over digit display. For example:

```
options(digits=10)
```

is supposed to give the calculation results in 10 digits till the end of R session. In the help file of R, the definition for digits parameter is as follows:

> digits: controls the number of digits
>   to print when printing numeric values.
>   It is a suggestion only. Valid values
>   are **1...22** with default **7**

So, it says this is a suggestion only. What if I like to always display 10 digits, not more or less?

My second question is, what if I like to display more than 22 digits, i.e. for more precise calculations like 100 digits? Is it possible with base R, or do I need an additional package/function for that?

**Edit:** Thanks to jmoy's suggestion, I tried `sprintf("%.100f",pi)` and it gave

```
[1] "3.1415926535897931159979634685441851615905761718750000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

which has 48 decimals. Is this the maximum limit R can handle?

Comment: Only the first 15 digits of pi are accurate.  Compare to the true value http://joyofpi.com/pi.html

Comment: You're right. Why is it different in R?

Comment: See the FAQ on R http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f

Comment: Mehper: I think that you're misinterpreting the computational representation of numbers in R. You might want to read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point.

Comment: As a comparison, Python does exactly the same: Try `python -c "import math; print(format(math.pi, '.100f'))"`. The result is `pi` with 48 "real" decimals, stuffed by zeroes for the remaining 52 digits.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The reason it is only a suggestion is that you could quite easily write a print function that ignored the options value.  The built-in printing and formatting functions do use the `options` value as a default.

As to the second question, since R uses finite precision arithmetic, your answers aren't accurate beyond 15 or 16 decimal places, so in general, more aren't required.  The [gmp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmp/index.html) and [rcdd](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rcdd/index.html) packages deal with multiple precision arithmetic (via an interace to the gmp library), but this is mostly related to big integers rather than more decimal places for your doubles.

[Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/products/mathematica/index.html) or [Maple](http://www.maplesoft.com/Products/Maple/) will allow you to give as many decimal places as your heart desires.

EDIT:
It might be useful to think about the difference between decimal places and significant figures.  If you are doing statistical tests that rely on differences beyond the 15th significant figure, then your analysis is almost certainly junk.

On the other hand, if you are just dealing with very small numbers, that is less of a problem, since R can handle number as small as `.Machine$double.xmin` (usually 2e-308).

Compare these two analyses.

```
x1 <- rnorm(50, 1, 1e-15)
y1 <- rnorm(50, 1 + 1e-15, 1e-15)
t.test(x1, y1)  #Should throw an error

x2 <- rnorm(50, 0, 1e-15)
y2 <- rnorm(50, 1e-15, 1e-15)
t.test(x2, y2)  #ok
```

In the first case, differences between numbers only occur after many significant figures, so the data are "nearly constant".  In the second case, Although the size of the differences between numbers are the same, compared to the magnitude of the numbers themselves they are large.

---

As mentioned by e3bo, you can use multiple-precision floating point numbers using the `Rmpfr` package.

```
mpfr("3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825")
```

These are slower and more memory intensive to use than regular (double precision) `numeric` vectors, but can be useful if you have a poorly conditioned problem or unstable algorithm.

Comment: As [this Rwiki page](http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=misc:r_accuracy:high_precision_arithmetic) demonstrates, the [Rmpfr package](http://cran.at.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpfr/index.html) allows for high precision floating point arithmetic in R.

Comment: But can Rmpfr be used by any R package to improve its precision? Or it can only use the functions coded internally on it?

Comment: I was thinking just that, " If you are doing statistical tests that rely on differences beyond the 15th significant figure, then your analysis is almost certainly junk." but I wondered what would be the number of digits at which I would conclude it's junk, and I thought 5, but I'd be happy to stand corrected.

Answer (score 62):

If you are producing the entire output yourself, you can use `sprintf()`, e.g.

```
> sprintf("%.10f",0.25)
[1] "0.2500000000"
```

specifies that you want to format a floating point number with ten decimal points (in `%.10f` the `f` is for float and the `.10` specifies ten decimal points).

I don't know of any way of forcing R's higher level functions to print an exact number of digits.

Displaying 100 digits does not make sense if you are printing R's usual numbers, since the best accuracy you can get using 64-bit doubles is around 16 decimal digits (look at .Machine$double.eps on your system). The remaining digits will just be junk.

Comment: Actually, some special chi-square tests I applied were needing hundreds of decimals to give accurate results. Also pi has thousands of decimals. That's why I was wondering about 100 or more digits.

Comment: pi has an infinite number of decimals; that doesn't mean that a computer can store them.

Comment: I guess this is an scenario where Mathematica is superior to R.

Comment: @skan Do you think Mathematica stores an infinite number of decimals?

Comment: @Gregor of course not, but you can as many digits as your memory lets you.

Answer (score 2):

One more solution able to control the how many decimal digits to print out based on needs (if you don't want to print redundant zero(s))

For example, if you have a vector as `elements` and would like to get `sum` of it

```
elements <- c(-1e-05, -2e-04, -3e-03, -4e-02, -5e-01, -6e+00, -7e+01, -8e+02)
sum(elements)
## -876.5432
```

Apparently, the last digital as `1` been truncated, the ideal result should be `-876.54321`, but if set as fixed printing decimal option, e.g `sprintf("%.10f", sum(elements))`, redundant zero(s) generate as `-876.5432100000`

Following the tutorial here: [printing decimal numbers](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2003-February/030267.html), if able to identify how many decimal digits in the certain numeric number, like here in `-876.54321`, there are 5 decimal digits need to print, then we can set up a parameter for `format` function as below:

```
decimal_length <- 5
formatC(sum(elements), format = "f", digits = decimal_length)
## -876.54321
```

We can change the `decimal_length` based on each time query, so it can satisfy different decimal printing requirement.

Answer (score 2):

If you work primarily with `tibble`s, there is a function that enforces digits: `num()`.

Here is an example:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- tribble(
  
~ weight, ~ weight_selfreport,
81.5,81.66969147005445,
72.6,72.59528130671505,
92.9,93.01270417422867,
79.4,79.4010889292196,
94.6,96.64246823956442,
80.2,79.4010889292196,
116.2,113.43012704174228,
95.4,95.73502722323049,
99.5,99.8185117967332
)

data <-
  data %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ num(., digits = 3)))

data
#> # A tibble: 9 × 2
#>      weight weight_selfreport
#>   <num:.3!>         <num:.3!>
#> 1    81.500            81.670
#> 2    72.600            72.595
#> 3    92.900            93.013
#> 4    79.400            79.401
#> 5    94.600            96.642
#> 6    80.200            79.401
#> 7   116.200           113.430
#> 8    95.400            95.735
#> 9    99.500            99.819
```

Thus you can even decide to have different rounding options depending on what your needs are. I find it very helpful and a rather quick solution to printing dfs.