# Formatting Decimal places in R

Tags: r, formatting, rounding, r-faq

I have a number, for example 1.128347132904321674821 that I would like to show as only two decimal places when output to screen (or written to a file). How does one do that?

```
x <- 1.128347132904321674821
```

EDIT:

The use of:

```
options(digits=2)
```

Has been suggested as a possible answer. Is there a way to specify this within a script for one-time use? When I add it to my script it doesn't seem to do anything different and I'm not interested in a lot of re-typing to format each number (I'm automating a very large report).

--

Answer: round(x, digits=2)

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287616/controlling-digits-in-r-language

Comment: If one uses options(digits=4), that doesn't limit the calculations to 4 digits, does it?  In that case it would make programs far less accurate.  It ONLY affects the number when it is printed, correct?

Comment: `controls the number of digits to print when printing numeric values. It is a suggestion only. Valid values are 1...22 with default 7. See the note in print.default about values greater than 15.` from ?options it only effects output.

Comment: Note that `round(23, digits=2)` will print `23` and not `23.00`. If you want the latter, try http://stackoverflow.com/a/12135122/180892

Comment: @PaulHurleyuk, I think it's good practice in programming to use the minimal number of libraries as possible. Someone who uses a different library for each trivial need usually ends up with a mess, big files, portability issues, etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228403/setting-default-number-of-decimal-places-for-printing

Answer (score 530, accepted):

**Background:** Some  answers suggested on this page (e.g., `signif`, `options(digits=...)`) do not guarantee that a certain number of decimals are displayed for an arbitrary number. I presume this is a design feature in R whereby good scientific practice involves showing a certain number of digits based on principles of "[significant figures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures)". However, in many domains (e.g., [APA style](http://my.ilstu.edu/%7Ejhkahn/apastats.html), business reports) formatting requirements dictate that a certain number of decimal places are displayed. This is often done for consistency and standardisation purposes rather than being concerned with significant figures.

**Solution**:

The following code shows exactly two decimal places for the number `x`.

```
format(round(x, 2), nsmall = 2)
```

For example:

```
format(round(1.20, 2), nsmall = 2)
# [1] "1.20"
format(round(1, 2), nsmall = 2)
# [1] "1.00"
format(round(1.1234, 2), nsmall = 2)
# [1] "1.12"
```

A more general function is as follows where `x` is the number and `k` is the number of decimals to show. `trimws` removes any leading white space which can be useful if you have a vector of numbers.

```
specify_decimal <- function(x, k) trimws(format(round(x, k), nsmall=k))
```

E.g.,

```
specify_decimal(1234, 5)
# [1] "1234.00000"
specify_decimal(0.1234, 5)
# [1] "0.12340"
```

**Discussion of alternatives:**

The [formatC answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36034593/180892) and [sprintf answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48265385/180892) work fairly well. But they will show negative zeros in some cases which may be unwanted. I.e.,

```
formatC(c(-0.001), digits = 2, format = "f")
# [1] "-0.00"
sprintf(-0.001, fmt = '%#.2f')
# [1] "-0.00"
```

One possible workaround to this is as follows:

```
formatC(as.numeric(as.character(round(-.001, 2))), digits = 2, format = "f")
# [1] "0.00"
```

Comment: +1 Only answer that worked for me, correctly prints `0.0001` as `0.00`

Comment: It's always bothered me how functions like `format()` and `prettyNum()` transform numerics into characters. How would you address this?

Comment: What's with the quotes that appear?

Comment: @F.Webber the variable becomes type "character" rather "numeric".

Comment: What about `format(round(98082706897709.000098754390, 2), nsmall=2)`?

Comment: @JeromyAnglim - How to round `8.1999999999999993` to `8.2`?

Comment: @JeromyAnglim I note that the solution above has a possible edge-case disadvantage of fixing the number of characters in front of the decimal, e.g. 
`format(c(10, 1), nsmall=1)` yields `"10.0" " 1.0"` (note the leading space in front of the 1.0. Whereas, the `sprintf()` function seems to guarantee nicer formatting on both sides of the decimal, e.g. `sprintf(c(10,1), fmt = '%#.1f')` gets rid of that pesky leading space and returns `"10.0" "1.0"`.

Comment: any of you guys could help on this one?
https://stackoverflow.com/q/53279593/5224236

Comment: The leading spaces are a feature designed to align the decimal point when the result of `format` is used in a column.

Comment: format(round(0.9995, 2), nsmall = 2) gives "1.00" however substr(0.9995, 1, 3) gives "0.99" . You could use substr(number, 1, 2+desire decimals)

Comment: This answer is incorrect .It does not always work. Try this: options(digits=22); format(round(1.1111111111111, 2), nsmall = 2)

Comment: @FedericoMolinaMagne 0.9995 rounds to 1.00. That is correct rounding behaviour.

Comment: @FengJiang This is not an issue with the function. Rather you should perhaps avoid setting the digits option too high. See warning in [print.default help](https://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/base/html/print.default.html). It warns that setting digits >=16 can cause print issues.

Comment: As of R `base` 4.3.1 (maybe prior), there is no need to use `round` and setting `digits` parameter on `format` is enough. _e.g._: `format(pi, digits = 2, nsmall = 2)` returns `"3.14"`, `format(-0, ...)` returns `"0.00"` or `format(2.199, ...)` returns `"2.20"`. It's important to note that `digits = 0` is *not* allowed, `sprintf("%.0f", <number>)` is the best option for that case.

Answer (score 54):

You can format a number, say `x`, up to decimal places as you wish. Here `x` is a number with many decimal places. Suppose we wish to show up to 8 decimal places of this number:

```
x = 1111111234.6547389758965789345
y = formatC(x, digits = 8, format = "f")
# [1] "1111111234.65473890"
```

Here `format="f"` gives floating numbers in the usual decimal places say, xxx.xxx, and `digits` specifies the number of digits. By contrast, if you wanted to get an integer to display you would use `format="d"` (much like `sprintf`).

Comment: While I'm unclear on exactly what the OP was asking, judging by the highest rated answer, I couldn't help but observe that `formatC` is almost exclusively what I use for this purpose. I think this answer is good and is in base R per the OP's request.

Comment: This answer works better than the selected answer. formatC is not impacted by options(digits)

Answer (score 39):

You can try my package [formattable](https://github.com/renkun-ken/formattable).

```
> # devtools::install_github("renkun-ken/formattable")
> library(formattable)
> x <- formattable(1.128347132904321674821, digits = 2, format = "f")
> x
[1] 1.13
```

The good thing is, `x` is still a numeric vector and you can do more calculations with the same formatting.

```
> x + 1
[1] 2.13
```

Even better, the digits are not lost, you can reformat with more digits any time :)

```
> formattable(x, digits = 6, format = "f")
[1] 1.128347
```

Comment: Such a tiny little prick bugging me whole morning. For some reason R would round up the display for some column only. I needed this fix as I had to perform calculations on those columns as well. This works. Thanks !

Comment: I like formattable than any baseR functions. The biggest advantage it retains the variable as numeric.

Answer (score 34):

for 2 decimal places assuming that you want to keep trailing zeros

```
sprintf(5.5, fmt = '%#.2f')
```

which gives

```
[1] "5.50"
```

As @mpag mentions below, it seems R can sometimes give unexpected values with this and the round method e.g. sprintf(5.5550, fmt='%#.2f') gives 5.55, not 5.56

Comment: however, although sprintf rounds, sprintf(5.5550, fmt='%#.2f') gives a slightly unexpected result: 5.55.  sprintf(5.555000000001, fmt='%#.2f') gives 5.56.  This appears to be a general "issue" with rounding in R, as the round, nsmall method gives the same.

Comment: Thanks @mpag, I had no idea that R struggled with rounding on boundaries, I've just tried it with 5.565 which does round up, while 5.545 rounds down. I guess it is the way they are handling floating point inprecision. 

I don't think I've seen this behaviour in other languages which I guess means they have a built-in workaround

Comment: I think rather that they're intentionally treating the values as limited in the degree of precision.  They are figuring that a value that is 5.555 is really just as likely to have resulted from a "real" value of 5.5546 as 5.5554. However, if you continue that sort of rounding game, 5.444445 might (untested) end up as "6" if you do it one digit at a time.  But you might be right that it might be a matter of the binary representation being a bit under or over 5.55.

Comment: Yeah, I think if it was intentional it would also be consistent between 5.565 and 5.545. The' randomness' suggests to me it's a floating point representation thing.

Answer (score 12):

Something like that :

```
options(digits=2)
```

Definition of digits option :

```
digits: controls the number of digits to print when printing numeric values.
```

Comment: Is there any way to set this dynamically when running a script?

Comment: This works for outputting within the R console, but doesn't work within my script (they still come out with .1289273982)

Comment: I get a weird behavior, the `digits` option doesn't seem to set the number of digits after decimal. E.g., when I set options(digits = 2), then printing 7.25 results in the output of 7.2, 1234.25 becomes 1234, and 0.25 remains 0.25. Is there another option interacting with this?

Comment: This is something you definitely should NOT do, if you just need one time use. Change options will impact everything.

Answer (score 12):

If you prefer significant digits to fixed digits then, the [signif](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/VFP/versions/1.0/topics/Signif) command might be useful:

```
> signif(1.12345, digits = 3)
[1] 1.12
> signif(12.12345, digits = 3)
[1] 12.1
> signif(12345.12345, digits = 3)
[1] 12300
```

Comment: Thanks Paul. These two weren't exactly what I was looking for, but signif led me to round() which is exactly what I needed. Cheers,

Comment: `Error: could not find function "fixed"`

Comment: `signif` works for the specific number provided, but I presume the common applied problem is when you need to show exactly two decimal places but you don't know what the number is ahead of time. In that case, `signif` will give different numbers of decimals depending on the actual number.

Comment: fixed is not found anywhere. Please fix it, otherwise this misleading answer should be deleted.

Comment: @JeromyAnglim how do we fix that when we want 3sf? sometimes it gives me 3sf, other times 4sf, etc. how do we fix this?

Answer (score 10):

Check functions **prettyNum, format**

to have trialling zeros (123.1240 for example) use `sprintf(x, fmt='%#.4g')`

Comment: @42 I would advocate to learn `sprintf`, it is basically a framework for formatting

Comment: @jangorecki I'm not sure of your point. All I did  (5+ years ago) was suggest a spelling correction.

Comment: @42 I tougth you complain on the `fmt` arg, sorry!

Comment: I think the OP is after fixed decimal places rather than fixed digits. It seems the `g` in your answer is for fixed digits, using `f` works better.

Answer (score 5):

The function `formatC()` can be used to format a number to two decimal places. Two decimal places are given by this function even when the resulting values include trailing zeros.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using this variant for force print K decimal places:

```
# format numeric value to K decimal places
formatDecimal <- function(x, k) format(round(x, k), trim=T, nsmall=k)
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that numeric objects in R are stored with [double precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision), which gives you (roughly) 16 decimal digits of precision - the rest will be noise. I grant that the number shown above is probably just for an example, but it is 22 digits long.

Comment: Confirmed, it's just for an example. I mashed the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like to would be something like

```
library(tutoR)
format(1.128347132904321674821, 2)
```

Per a little [online help](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/tutoR/html/format.html).

Comment: I found this, but it requires a package, I'm looking for something within the base package.

Comment: @brandon, format() is part of base. Open up R and type ?format ... no packages needed.

Comment: Hrmmm, did you look at what this outputs? [1] "1.128347" otherwise, you're quite right about it being in the base package, my bad.

Comment: Perhaps try  `format.default(x, digits = 2)` just a shot in the dark though based on the link provided. That info is some what lacking from what I normally read for documentation, I expected to see the printed outputs as well.

Comment: Just noticed that your link points to tutoR documentation, which is not part of the base.

Comment: It's just amazing how many times "format" turns out to be the right answer. It has a large number of methods, as I suspect you know, but others should try `methods(format)`.

Comment: `format(0.0002, 2)` will output `0` instead of `0.00`, which I assume is the intended.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)
# round the numbers
df <- df %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), .fns = function(x) {format(round(x, 2), nsmall = 2)}))
```

Here I am changing all numeric values to have only 2 decimal places. If you need to change it to more decimal places

```
# round the numbers for k decimal places
df <- df %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), .fns = function(x) {format(round(x, k), nsmall = k)}))
```

Replace the k with the desired number of decimal places

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to round a number or a list, simply use

```
round(data, 2)
```

Then, data will be round to 2 decimal place.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this function that could be improve but looks like works well in corner cases. For example, in the case of 0.9995 the vote correct answer gives us 1.00 which is incorrect. I use that solution in the case that the number has no decimals.

```
round_correct <- function(x, digits, chars = TRUE) {
  if(grepl(x = x, pattern = "\\.")) {
    y <- as.character(x)
    pos <- grep(unlist(strsplit(x = y, split = "")), pattern = "\\.", value = FALSE)
    if(chars) {
      return(substr(x = x, start = 1, stop = pos + digits))
    }
    return(
      as.numeric(substr(x = x, start = 1, stop = pos + digits))
    )
  } else {
    return(
      format(round(x, 2), nsmall = 2)
    )
  }
}
```

Example:

```
round_correct(10.59648, digits = 2)
[1] "10.59"
round_correct(0.9995, digits = 2)
[1] "0.99"
round_correct(10, digits = 2)
[1] "10.00"
```

Comment: 10.59648 rounded by 2 digits gives here 10.59. Shouldn't it be 10.60? Same with 0.9995, which should result in 1.00, not in 0.99.

Answer (score 0):

here's my approach from units to millions.
digits parameter let me  adjust the minimum number of significant values (integer + decimals). You could adjust decimal rounding inside first.

```
number <-function(number){
  result <- if_else(
    abs(number) < 1000000,
    format(
      number, digits = 3,
      big.mark = ".",
      decimal.mark = ","
    ),
    paste0(
      format(
        number/1000000,
        digits = 3,
        drop0trailing = TRUE,
        big.mark = ".",
        decimal.mark = ","
      ),
      "MM"
    )
  )
  # result <- paste0("$", result)
  return(result)
}
```