# Creating a latex table from ftable object in R

Tags: r, latex, xtable, knitr

Let me create some data before I ask my question.

```
 my.data <- data.frame(A = sample(seq(1,100,by=5),10,replace=TRUE),W = rnorm(10),X =sample(1:10),Y = sample(c("yes", "no"), 10, replace = TRUE),Z=sample(c('a','b','c','d'),10,replace=TRUE))

attach(my.data)

my.d <- xtabs(W~Z+Y+A);my.d
table.data <- ftable(my.d)

result1 <- round(table.data,2)
```

result1 looks like ..

```
      A     6    11    16    26    71    76    86    91
Z Y                                                    
a no     0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
 yes    0.00  0.56  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.79  0.00  0.01

b no     0.61  0.00 -0.22  0.14  0.00  0.00 -0.08  1.71
  yes    0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00

c no     0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.08  0.00  0.00  0.00
  yes    0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00

d no     0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  1.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
  yes    0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
```

I am actually writing an article using knitr package. 
    Is there a way to transform result1 into a latex table 
automatically when my *.rnw file is complied ?

I tried with xtable but got the following error...

```
Error in UseMethod("xtable") :   no applicable method for 'xtable' applied to an object of class "ftable"
```

Thank you @DWin and @Yihui. Apart from latex(), I also used xtable as stated under

```
print(xtable(ftable2data.frame(result1)))
```

To remove unnecessary row names I did the following

```
print(xtable(ftable2data.frame(result1)),include.rownames=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Method 1:

```
require(MIfuns)
require(Hmisc)
latex(ftable2data.frame(result1))
```

Comment: latex(ftable2data.frame(result1)) does not seem to be responding @ DWin

Comment: You supporting LaTeX setup may be different than mine.

Comment: I guess you need to prevent `latex()` from compiling the tex file automatically (by default): use `latex(ftable2data.frame(result1), file='')`; also remember to set the chunk option `results=asis` or `results=tex`

Comment: This package is no longer available. `install.packages("MIfuns")
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘MIfuns’ is not available (for R version 3.1.2)` (It was replaced by `memisc`, see David's answer.

Answer (score 8):

As an alternative, memisc provides toLatex methods for ftable objects.

```
library(memisc)
toLatex(result1)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the package [`xtable`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/xtable.pdf):

```
library(xtable)
mytable=ftable(mydata)
print(
  xtable(format(mytable)),file="~/Desktop/mytable.tex"
)
```

I don't know how it compares to the other options given.

Comment: Simple and without extra packages, although it requires a little bit of adaptation.

Answer (score 2):

Building off of user2030503's answer,

```
# install.packages('simsalapar')
library(simsalapar)
utils::toLatex(result1)
```

The function toLatex is an S3 generic so passes to `simsalapar:::toLatex.ftable()` when given an ftable object. Alternatively you can just do `simsalapar:::toLatex.ftable(result1)`.

Once that was done I needed to include `\usepackage{booktabs}` in the latex preamble as `toLatex.ftable` uses `\toprule`. Alternatively you can pass `booktabs=FALSE`.

It also looks like `toLatex.ftable` trims out trailing zeroes. To fix that this is what I did (see the answer to [Formatting Decimal places in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443687/formatting-decimal-places-in-r) for `format()`):

```
result1[1:nrow(result1),1:ncol(result1)] %<>% as.numeric %>% format(nsmall=2,digits=3)
```

this converts the matrix of the ftable to a character matrix, but `toLatex.ftable` still works.

I also found it helpful to `\usepackage{pdflscape}` and wrap my table with `\begin{landscape}` and `\end{landscape}` because these contingency tables can be quite wide.

Comment: how do I save the file into a `.tex` file?

Comment: my bad on my last comment; here if a simple way to do it. First, let's say we have `table_to_LaTeX<-utils::toLatex(result1)`, and then we write those line on the disk with:  `writeLines(table_to_LaTeX, "file_name.tex")`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `toLatex()` function provided by the [simsalapar](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/simsalapar/index.html) Package.

```
library(simsalapar)
toLatex(result1)
```