# Include dimension names in row and column headers for LaTeX-formatted contingency table

Tags: r, xtable

If the categories of the attributes in a contingency table are mere numbers, using only these numbers as column/row header is not enough -- a description what the numbers mean is called for. The picture below shows the cross-classification of household size vs. number of foreigners in a household sample:

[image: Example table]

Does anyone have experience in producing such tables using R+LaTeX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's `ftable` that turns a contingency table into a two-dimensional formatted table and allows specifying what is shown in rows and what in columns (also useful for tables of more than two dimensions). The `memisc` package helps turning this into nice LaTeX:

```
library(magrittr)
library(memisc)
expand.grid(Foreigners = 0:5, `Total persons` = 1:8) %>%
  cbind(Freq = rnorm(6*8, 20, 10)) %>%
  xtabs(formula = Freq~.) %>%
  ftable %>%
  toLatex
```

No hacking needed, and LaTeX can be used for the names of the columns in `expand.grid` (to support e.g. rotation and/or spanning multiple rows). The generated LaTeX code requires the `booktabs` and `dcolumn` packages.

[image: Compiled output]

Related: [Creating a latex table from ftable object in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9658372/946850).

Answer (score 6):

I have a rather hackish solution of my own, but I'd like to see other approaches, too. Of course, it would be nice if a variant of this code was added to `xtable`.

My solution consists of updating the `rownames()` and `colnames()` of the table. The row header goes into `rownames()[1]`, and the column header goes into `colnames()[1]`. Several things have to be remembered:

- The number of columns in the resulting table is one larger if using row headers.
  Hence, the `tabular` environment must be created by the user.
- If a row header is added, the column header has to include an additional `&`
- Do not sanitize or otherwise reformat row or column names after this operation

The `add.crosstab.headers` function takes care of everything. It can be applied to the result of an `xtable()` call. Some helper functions are needed, too.

```
macrify <- function(m, s, bs='\\') {
  paste(bs, m, '{', s, '}', sep='')
}

boldify <- function(s) {
  macrify('textbf', s)
}

add.crosstab.headers <- function(t, row.header=NA, col.header=NA,
                                 sanitize=boldify) {
  rownames(t) <- sanitize(rownames(t))
  colnames(t) <- sanitize(colnames(t))
  if (!is.na(row.header)) {
    colnames(t)[1] <- paste('&', colnames(t)[1])
    rownames(t) <- paste('&', rownames(t))
    row.header <- sanitize(row.header)
    row.header <- macrify('rotatebox{90}', row.header)
    multirow <- macrify('multirow', nrow(t))
    multirow <- macrify(multirow, '*', bs='')
    row.header <- macrify(multirow, row.header, bs='')
    rownames(t)[1] <- paste(row.header, rownames(t)[1])
  }
  if (!is.na(col.header)) {
    col.header <- sanitize(col.header)
    multicolumn <- macrify('multicolumn', ncol(t))
    multicolumn <- macrify(multicolumn, 'c', bs='')
    col.header <- macrify(multicolumn, col.header, bs='')
    col.header <- paste(col.header, '\\\\\n')
    col.header <- paste(col.header, '&')
    if (!is.na(row.header)) {
      col.header <- paste('&', col.header)
    }
    colnames(t)[1] <- paste(col.header, colnames(t)[1])
  }
  t
}
```

The usage would be like this.

```
dat <- matrix(round(rnorm(9, 20, 10)), 3, 3)
t <- xtable(dat)
t <- add.crosstab.headers(t, row.header='Foreigners', col.header='Total persons')

print.xtable(t,
             only.contents=TRUE,
             booktabs=TRUE
             , sanitize.text.function=identity
             )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach. Start with some data (you should do this when posting the question) in matrix form.

```
dat<-matrix(round(rnorm(9,20,10)),3,3)
```

Create a vector of names. Apply the names to the matrix. Print the matrix

```
persons<-c(seq("0","2"))
foreign<-c(seq("0","2"))
dimnames(dat)<-list(persons=persons, foreign=foreign)
dat
```

You can use xtable to output a Latex-formatted table.

```
library(xtable)
xtable(dat)
```

Comment: Sure I should have posted a minimal working example. Sorry for not doing it. Do you mind if I adapt your example? -- The generated xtable does not include the dimension names, though.

Comment: No problem.  And yes, I realized afterwards that the latex output doesn't include the dimension names.  My approach would probably be to just fix that in tex itself, though if you figure out how to do it directly using xtable do let me know.

Comment: See my own answer for an `xtable` solution.