# adding rows or boldify single row.names with print.xtables – add something in between rows?

Tags: r, latex, xtable

I try to use `print.xtable` `add.to.row` to get table formatted like this:

**sports**

```
share of ballers    22.3 
share of skiers      4.6
```

**addiction**

```
share of smokers    20.3 
share of drinkers    6.6
```

My R table does contain the additional row.names even if these rows don't contain any values. I used the add.to.row option to add colors to the different rows like suggested [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7952/how-to-create-coloured-tables-with-sweave-and-xtable) which worked fine. But what does not work is to add bold text with xtable or add additional `hline` between the rows. I always get an error message like:

`Bad type area settings!` The detected line width is about 52 % (typearea) larger than the heuristically determined line width.

So this could mean the table gets to big for its environment because of my changes, but do not have an idea what to do about it. Note I have reads posts like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703802/include-dimension-names-in-row-and-column-headers-for-latex-formatted-contingenc) that modifies the xtable output itself, but even though this might possible for me to I am looking for an easier solution. Because if I go for this solution I had to `capture.output` and use regexp replacement to add something in between.

Is there a way around this? Or is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the `hline` part, see `?print.xtable`.

> `hline.after`: When '`type="latex"`', a vector of numbers between -1 and 
>             '`"nrow(x)"`', inclusive, indicating the rows after which a 
>             horizontal line should appear

To embolden all you rows names:

```
bold.allrows <- function(x) {
  h <- paste('\\textbf{',x,'}', sep ='')
  h
}
print(xtable(yourTable), 
      sanitize.rownames.function =  bold.allrows)
```

To embolden some row names, you can add a " special markup" to those rows, e.g. `BOLD`:

```
bold.somerows <- 
        function(x) gsub('BOLD(.*)',paste('\\\\textbf{\\1','}'),x)

print(xtable(yourTable), 
      sanitize.rownames.function =  bold.somerows)
```

e.g:

```
require(xtable)
hh <- head(mtcars)[ , c(1:5)]
## I want to bold 1 and 3 rows 
rownames(hh)[c(1, 3)] <- paste('BOLD', rownames(hh)[c(1, 3)])
print(xtable(hh), sanitize.rownames.function =  bold.somerows)
```

Comment: +1 for the pointer. lost track a little bit here after all this docu. However hline seems to be limited to only hline. Something simlar that does a little more like spacing or inser characters would be perfect.

Comment: where exactly  do you want insert character?

Comment: Row names for example. Like in my example. Adding the row names of the bold section headers would be cool. I would not have to add them to my R table then.

Comment: thx for the effort. But still the problem is, that I just want to boldify some of the rows like in the example.

Comment: At the end of the day I guess you are right,gotta use gsub somewhere here, tried to avoid it :).