# Setting default number of decimal places for printing

Tags: r, decimal

I am running code to produce outputs where I want all the outputs to be printed with 1 decimal place. However the code uses functions which I use generally and I don't want to specify within these that the printed output is rounded.

The answers to this question [Formatting Decimal places in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443687/formatting-decimal-places-in-r) suggest using `options(digits=2)` or `round(x, digits=2)`.

The first option is a general setting which is great for rounding `1.234` to `1.2` but would print `12.345` as `12`

The second option would work if put within the function but I don't want to touch them. How to set this generally?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do this:

```
print <- function(x, ...) {
    if (is.numeric(x)) base::print(round(x, digits=2), ...) 
    else base::print(x, ...)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. In attempting this I arrived at the same problem as setting options(digits=2)    
   - `#load print function
    x <- 12.34
    z = print(x)
    [1] 12` -

    Is there something i'm missing?

Comment: did you reset the `digits` option to its default? try it again in a fresh session.

Answer (score 5):

I like `formatC` for printing numbers with a specified number of decimal places. That way, `1` should always be printed as `"1.0"` when `digits = 1` and `format = "f"`. You can create an S3 print method for objects of class numeric such as the following:

```
print.numeric<-function(x, digits = 1) formatC(x, digits = digits, format = "f")

print(1)
# [1] "1.0"

print(12.4)
# [1] "12.4"

print(c(1,4,6.987))
# [1] "1.0" "4.0" "7.0"

print(c(1,4,6.987), digits = 3)
# [1] "1.000" "4.000" "6.987"
```