# Why does not R round function round big numbers

Tags: r, math, statistics, rounding

I need a R function that always returns same number of digits after the decimal point regardless of how big the argument is. I tried round() but it does not work this way. Here is my example:

```
Rweb:> round(111234.678912,4) # expect 111234.6789
[1] 111234.7 
Rweb:> round(111234.678912/10,4) # expect 11123.4679    
[1] 11123.47 
Rweb:> round(111234.678912/100,4) # expect 1112.3468      
[1] 1112.347 
Rweb:> round(111234.678912/1000,4)     
[1] 111.2347 
Rweb:> round(111234.678912/10000,4)     
[1] 11.1235
```

It does work if the argument is in exponential format but I need work with numbers in floating format.

Comment: This type of question gets asked a lot (for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5458729/1281189)). Perhaps worthy of FAQ status?

Comment: @BenBarnes I'm tempted to agree with you, but OTOH the same "gotcha" happens in M**lab  and other languages, not to mention Ex**l .  At some point users need some basic training in the difference between display and stored values, regardless of the language in question.

Comment: @BenBarnes: the linked question is about trailing zeroes, which isn't really the same thing.

Comment: @DavidRobinson, you're right. The previously linked question wasn't exactly the same thing. I meant something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3443687/1281189) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2287616/1281189) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11228403/1281189) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8169406/1281189)

Comment: But for some reason, I thought I had copied [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3245862/1281189) link into the above comment, which is nearly exactly the question here.

Comment: For anyone else who, like me, thought the question was going to be about bignums :-),  there's this:  `Rgames> bfoo<-mpfr("1.234545678909887665453421")
Rgames> bfoo
1 'mpfr' number of precision  84   bits 
[1] 1.234545678909887665453421
Rgames> round(bfoo,10)
1 'mpfr' number of precision  84   bits 
[1] 1.23454567889999999999999999`

Answer (score 18):

It *does* round the number to the correct number of digits. However, R has limits on the number of digits it displays of very large numbers. That is- those digits are there, they just aren't shown.

You can see this like so:

```
> round(111234.678912,4)
[1] 111234.7
> round(111234.678912,4) - 111234
[1] 0.6789
```

You can use `formatC` to display it with any desired number of digits:

```
> n = round(111234.678912,4)
> formatC(n, format="f")
[1] "111234.6789"
> formatC(n, format="f", digits=2)
[1] "111234.68"
```

As @mnel helpfully points out, you can also set the number of digits shown (including those to the left of the decimal point) using `options`:

```
> options(digits=6)
> round(111234.678912,4)
[1] 111235
> options(digits=10)
> round(111234.678912,4)
[1] 111234.6789
```

Comment: Might be worth noting  can change number the digits by setting `options(digits)`

Answer (score 3):

```
let x is a number with big decimal places.
x<-1111111234.6547389758965789345
```

Here x is a number with big decimal places , you can format decimal places 
   as your wish.
 Such that we wish to take up to 8 decimal places of this number.

```
 x<-c(1111111234.6547389758965789345)
y<-formatC(x,digits=8,format="f")
 [1] "1111111234.65473890"
```

Here format="f" gives number in the usual decimal places say, xxx.xxx.
  But if you wanted to get  a integer number from this object x you use
   format="d"

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who, like me, thought the question was going to be about bignums :-),  there's this to ponder :-)

```
 Rgames> bfoo<-mpfr("1.234545678909887665453421")
 Rgames> bfoo
 1 'mpfr' number of precision  84   bits 
  [1] 1.234545678909887665453421
 Rgames> round(bfoo,10)
 1 'mpfr' number of precision  84   bits 
 [1] 1.23454567889999999999999999`
```

Answer (score 0):

About "bignums", @Carl Witthoft:
Thanks, Carl.  ... I did think about bignums, when I read it.  Are you sure there
's a problem with the rounding?
See this:

```
> mpfr("1.2345456789", prec=84)
1 'mpfr' number of precision  84   bits
[1] 1.23454567889999999999999999
```

and note that Rmpfr (I'm the maintainer) does stay close to the underlying MPFR library.  For `round()`, I've applied the logic/principle of f(x) returning a result with the same formal precision as x.  If you want rounding with decreased formal precision, you can conveniently use `roundMpfr()`:

```
> roundMpfr(bfoo, 32)
1 'mpfr' number of precision  32   bits 
[1] 1.2345456788
```