# keep pre-specified decimal values in R

Tags: r

I have a vector with values such as `0.953, 0.952, 0.07555 .`.
I just want to keep the first two decimal values. In other words, I just want to transform the above list as `0.95, 0.95, 0.08`.How to do this in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach.

Idea borrowed from [Formatting Decimal places in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443687/formatting-decimal-places-in-r)

```
# A useful function that you can use anytime. 
specify_decimal <- function(x, k) format(round(x, k), nsmall=k)

data <- c(0.953, 0.952, 0.07555)

specify_decimal(x=data, k= 2) 
[1] "0.95" "0.95" "0.08"
```