# R change decimal place without round off

Tags: r, dataframe, decimalformat

```
> signif(1.89,digits=2)
[1] 1.9
```

I'd like to have 1.8

Comment: `floor(1.89*10)/10` maybe?

Comment: That's the best I can come up with as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit clunky, but it will work and keep everything numeric:

```
x <- 1.829380

trunc.dec <- function(x,n) {
  floor(x*10^n)/10^n
}
```

Result:

```
trunc.dec(x,1)
#[1] 1.8
trunc.dec(x,2)
#[1] 1.82
trunc.dec(x,3)
#[1] 1.829
trunc.dec(x,4)
#[1] 1.8293
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> format(round(1.20, 2), nsmall = 2)
[1] "1.20"
> format(round(1, 2), nsmall = 2)
[1] "1.00"
> format(round(1.1234, 2), nsmall = 2)
[1] "1.12"
```

try this variation from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443687/formatting-decimal-places-in-r) article so you can have more samples.