# R. How to set a variable equal to a digit in some decimal place

Tags: r

I am new to R. I am trying to set y equal to 3 decimal place of x so

```
x=3.45678
round(x, digits = 3)
x
```

I get x = 3.457, And want to set y equal to 7 in this case.

Comment: Is this what you want? - [R change decimal place without round off](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24601887/r-change-decimal-place-without-round-off)

Comment: just ran it in r, you are right.

Comment: @thelatemail. No. For example: if x =1.234, I want y = 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it all numeric, which should be reasonably quick:

```
nthdigit <- function(x,n) {
  m <- round(x,digits=n)*10^(n-1)
  (m - floor(m))*10
}

nthdigit(x,3)
#[1] 7
```

Timings seem reasonable over here:

```
x <- rep(3.45678,1e7)  # 10 million cases
system.time(nthdigit(x,3))
#   user  system elapsed (seconds)
#   1.17    0.00    1.19
```

Comment: Thank you. I can't figure out how would I do the same thing but without rounding procedure. Just take the digit that I want and set it equal to a variable

Comment: @Artem :  `nthdigit <- function(x,n) {  m <- floor(x*10^n)/10;(m - floor(m))*10}`

Answer (score 0):

Deleting all the digits and decimal point prior to the nth-rounded last digit, with optional reversion to numeric:

```
> sub("\\d*\\.\\d{2}","", round(x,3) )
[1] "7"
> as.numeric( sub("\\d*\\.\\d{2}","", round(x,3) ) )
[1] 7
```