# transfer MATLAB data into R

Tags: r, matlab

I am trying to use the readMat command in R to read in some Matlab arrays. The numbers are in long format in matlab, 12345.67, to be more specific. However, when reading in, R rounds up to 12345.6, which is not what I want. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: I don't know the nuances of R so I can't say this for sure, but I think you're looking at display formatting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443687/formatting-decimal-places-in-r

Comment: thank you for responding, yes, that works great!