# Store a numeric variable with more decimals

Tags: r

I'm trying to store a numeric value into a variable.

```
x <- 1.124600011
```

This however gives me the following

> x
>      [1] 1.1246

Also storing it as numeric value does not work. Any thought on how I can store all the decimals?

Comment: there's nothing wrong, just that by default the print method shows less digits than you might want. `print(x, digits = 15)` will show you more (you can set this in `?options`)

Comment: As @baptiste said, this is printing related. You can check this question for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443687/formatting-decimal-places-in-r