# R - conditional formatting of numbers (decimal places)

Tags: r

I'm building a shiny app in R, one of the outputs of which is a table with summary data. The values appearing in this table are very variable - from 0.003 to 3,450,023.

I would like to have a way in which I can format the numbers for display so that, for example, numbers less than 0 are always displayed with three decimal places, numbers between 0 and 10 get one decimal place and everything else gets no decimal place at all, simply to make it easier for the user to read the data.

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443687/formatting-decimal-places-in-r) which fixes the number of decimal places, which is not what I want. I've also played with `signif` which restricts the number of digits, leading to scientific notation of large numbers which is not suitable for the audience.

Before I go and build a little function to sort this out for me, is there a built-in way to do this in R?

Comment: You know about `sprintf`, `formatC` and `prettyNum`? If none of those work then you probably should write your own function.

Comment: Yes I am familiar with all of them but they won't return quite what I want in one call. I've ended up writing a function pretty much like the one below. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably There has no Format function in R which works at a time based on different conditions. You can apply format function based on this condition :

```
           number <-function(number){
           if(number<0){
           result <- format(number,nsmall = 3)
           }else if(number %in% 0:10){
           result <-  format(number , nsmall = 1)
           }else{
           result <- format(number , nsmall=0)
           }
           return(result)
           }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very similar to what I've ended up writing, too.