# How to change number of decimal places displayed in output of multilevel model

Tags: r

I am displaying a multilevel model and would like to show three decimal places when output to screen.

```
M3 <- lmer(stflife ~ sclmeet + health + wkdcorga + hincfel + fltlnl 
           + rshpsts + dosprt + c_corruption_2014 + c_ticpi_2014  + 
             (1 | cntry), data = countries) 
display(M3)
```

Comment: `options(digits=3)` ?   May be a duplicate of [Formatting Decimal places in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3443687/4752675)

Comment: I tried but I am not sure I am inserting it well in my code as it shows errors. How should I integrate it in the model above?

Comment: Just add `options(digits=3)`  as a separate statement right before your statement `display(M3)`

Comment: it is still showing only two without any error

Comment: OH!   I though that your problem was that you were showing too many digits.  You know without your data, we cannot run your code and see what you see. It does seem unlikely that all coefficients would actually only have two significant digits.

Comment: So do you have any suggestion for me?

Comment: Sorry, but no. I did not understand your problem and I do not have an answer for it now that you have clarified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is the `display` function from the `arm` package, `display(M3, digits=3)` will display results to three decimal places. The `digits` argument is documented in the help for `display`, which can be accessed by running `?display`.