# How to keep the value length in output file after division operation in R?

Tags: r

I need to format a file. I have one column need to division by 1000000.
After the division operation, the new column will output.

I check the output file. Some values after division operation, the end of zero will be remove.
For example input 212740 212740/1000000=0.212740, the output is 0.21274. But I need my value is 0.212740.

How should I do to keep the end of zero in the value?
I am think maybe I can edit my write.table function?
Any suggestions for this?

my code:

```
A$cM=A[,c(4)]/1000000
write.table(file,'BigXP5.txt', sep=' ', quote=F, row.names=F, col.names=F);
```

Thanks

Victor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

`format(212740/1000000,nsmall=6)` that give you `0.212740` output

and for your dataset use

`A$cM=format(A[,c(4)]/1000000,nsmall=6)`

for more cases see [Formatting Decimal places in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443687/formatting-decimal-places-in-r)