# R numeric to char precision loss

Tags: r, type-conversion, precision

I want to convert my many-digit numeric vector to character. I tried the following solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12135122/5224236) which works for one number but not for a vector. This is OK

```
options(digits=20)
options(scipen=99999)
x<-129483.19999999999709;format(round(x, 12), nsmall = 12)
[1] "129483.199999999997"
```

But this is not. how to keep numeric precision in characters for numeric vectors?

```
> y <- c(129483.19999999999709, 1.3546746874,687676846.2546746464)
```

Specially problematic is `687676846.2546746464` Also tried:

```
> specify_decimal(y, 12)
[1] "129483.199999999997"    "1.354674687400"         "687676846.254674673080"
> formatC(y, digits = 12, format = "f")
[1] "129483.199999999997"    "1.354674687400"         "687676846.254674673080"
> formattable(y, digits = 12, format = "f")
[1] 129483.199999999997    1.354674687400         687676846.254674673080
> sprintf(y, fmt='%#.12g')
[1] "129483.200000" "1.35467468740" "687676846.255"
> sprintf(y, fmt='%#.22g')
[1] "129483.1999999999970896" "1.354674687399999966075" "687676846.2546746730804"
```

Expected result:

```
[1] "129483.199999999997" "1.354674687400" "687676846.254674646400"
```

It seems that precision loss occurs once only, it is not repeated.

```
> require(dplyr)
> convert <- function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))
> 687676846.2546746464 %>% convert
[1] 687676846.25467503
> 687676846.2546746464 %>% convert %>% convert %>% convert
[1] 687676846.25467503
```

Here I only have 5-digit precision, but more problematic I can't know beforehand what precision I am going to get..

Comment: `as.numeric(as.character(129483.123456789)) == 129483.123456789` prints `TRUE`.  I think there are two issues here.  First, what is printed to the console may not reflect the underlying precision.  Second, your sample number is floating point, and due to rounding error there could be some issues there.  If you check my example number, rounding won't be a problem.

Comment: well, what about my number?

Comment: character strings should definitely show all the digits

Comment: What _about_ your number?  It should behave the same as any number, expect that because your number has so many decimal places, there could be rounding issues happening here as well.

Comment: ok well so my question is how to circumvent those rounding issues

Comment: as mentioned I need a character string with all digits

Comment: Check here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443687/formatting-decimal-places-in-r, I think this code will do for your case: `x<-129483.19999999999709;format(round(x, 14), nsmall = 14)`

Comment: thanks for the try, but see edits, it doesn't work for all numbers

Comment: If you are doing this because you want to write a number to a text file in such a way that you can recover exactly the same number when you read the text file, perhaps you could convert it to its binary representation (abbreviated as hex).

Comment: Thanks John, indeed this is part of the problem, I also need for some reason to have 15 trailing zeroes to ensure format is recognized during upload. will dig hex

Answer (score 1):

At the end I could do what I wanted using these functions. `addtrailingzeroes` will add a number of zeroes after decimal to x.

```
nbdec <- function(x) {
  x1 <- as.character(x)
  xsplit <- strsplit(x1,"\\.")
  xlength <- sapply(xsplit, function(d) nchar(d)[2])
  xlength <- ifelse(is.na(xlength), 0, xlength)
  return(xlength)
}

trailingzeroes <- function(x, dig) {
  res <- rep(NA, length(x))
  for( i in 1:length(x)) {
    if(!is.na(x[i])) res[i] <- { paste0(rep(0,max(0,dig-nbdec(x[i]))), collapse="") }
    else { res[i] <- ""}
    }
return(res)
}

trailingcommas <- function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), NA, ifelse(nbdec(x)==0, ".",""))

addtrailingzeroes <- function(x, digits) {
  return(ifelse(!is.na(x), paste0(x, trailingcommas(x), trailingzeroes(x, digits)),NA))
}
```

However to suppress inaccuracies and rounding mistakes, x has to be cropped first using `roundnumerics.max`:

```
roundnumerics.max <- function(df, startdig=12) {
  for(icol in 1:ncol(df)) {
    if( is.numeric(df[,icol])) {
      dig <- startdig
      while(any(!as.numeric(as.character(df[,icol])) %==% df[,icol])) {
        dig <- dig-1
        df[,icol] <- round(df[,icol], digits=dig)
        if(dig==0) {
          break
          pprint("ERROR: zero numeric accuracy")
        }
      } 
      pprint("Numeric accuracy for column ",icol," ", colnames(df)[icol], " is ", dig)
    }
  }
  return(data.frame(df, stringsAsFactors = F))
}
```

This is slow and far from elegant... I still think it hard to believe that R has such an accuracy limitation to 16 significant digits, **and** adds inaccurate noise that causes divergences when you try to increase the `digits` option...**Without** letting you know...