# R print a number with decimal places and the number must NOT be in string format

Tags: r

I'm working on a HackerRank samples. For some reasons, the output needs to have 1 decimal place even if the actual number is a round number.

For example, even though my answer is theoretically correct, which is 32, HackerRank considers it as false because 32 is not 32.0

I've also tried

```
format(32, nsmall = 1)
```

But this is still an error because the output comes with " ".

I've looked into [Formatting Decimal places in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443687/formatting-decimal-places-in-r), but this doesn't answer my question.

The output must not be "32.0", it must be 32.0

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have no idea what "Hacker Rank samples" are and you don't say what exactly needs to be submitted and is tested. Maybe `print(format(32, nsmall = 1), quote = FALSE)`?

Comment: I'm working on this example https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/s10-weighted-mean/problem, the expected result is 32.0. But my R output wouldn't show the decimal, therefore my answer is considered false. I tried your solution but it gives an error because of the [1] that comes with the output.

Comment: I'm not impressed by how they check results. Anyway, `cat(format(32, nsmall = 1))`.

Comment: @Roland, you're so kind with words. It's just too atrocious to me to be honest. But recruiters are using this platform to test out coding skills which I have to take.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Roland for the tips. The below is accepted.

```
cat(format(32, nsmall = 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think below code should work:

```
# devtools::install_github("renkun-ken/formattable")
library(formattable)
p <- formattable(as.numeric("32"), digits = 1, format = "f")
p
```

Comment: Thanks but HackerRank doesn't allow you to use other libraries.