# NAs introduced by coercion WARNING while converting data to numeric from character

Tags: r, warnings, numeric

When I use `as.numeric` function on `chr` type data, I get the warning that I mentioned in the title. I tried some recommended ways like `x <- gsub(",","",x)` then `as.numeric(x)` . When I used this way, even I didn't get any warning, I see my variable is still `chr`  when I used `is.numeric(x)`

What else can I do? By the way I am trying to work on
[this data](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/6c8c8061e028e6ed3f526969b56067e120201127191721/433c44) When I used `str()` function, I saw some variables are `chr` while some are `num`. I didn't understand this distinction too.

Here is my dput of my example data:

```
dput(RTG[6:10, 1:5] )

structure(list(Date = c("02.11.2020", "02.11.2020", "02.11.2020",  "02.11.2020", "02.11.2020"), Hour = c("5:00", "6:00", "7:00",  "8:00", "9:00"), Total..MWh. = c("25,441.34", "26,408.77", "27,850.92",  "32,157.29", "34,040.87"), Natural.Gas = c("7,933.72", "8,457.68",  "9,506.90", "10,778.43", "11,026.81"), Dammed.Hydro = c("685.28",  "1,055.67", "1,576.70", "4,423.02", "6,139.45")), row.names = 6:10, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you share some data with us? That will help.  Use a command like this:   `dput(df[1:10, 1:5] )`   You will need to replace df with the name of your dataset; the command will the print a command that replicates the first ten rows and first five columns of your data.  Make adjustments as needed.  Copy the output and put it in your question.

Comment: As there are 168 obs. of 18 variables, I can't put the output but when I make adjustment and save it as a new variable, characters are still characters. I add direct PDF link for my data. F.e. I am trying to convert "River" variable into numeric. Because not all variables in data are character, somehow. F.e. "Sun" is numeric.

Comment: You don't need to send all your data.  Also, you can refer to specific variables, like this: 
 `dput(mtcars[1:10,c("mpg","hp")])`     So, just make a `dput` command for the 3 or 4 variables related to you problem, and send just 10 rows.

Comment: `structure(list(Date = c("02.11.2020", "02.11.2020", "02.11.2020", 
"02.11.2020", "02.11.2020"), Hour = c("5:00", "6:00", "7:00", 
"8:00", "9:00"), Total..MWh. = c("25,441.34", "26,408.77", "27,850.92", 
"32,157.29", "34,040.87"), Natural.Gas = c("7,933.72", "8,457.68", 
"9,506.90", "10,778.43", "11,026.81"), Dammed.Hydro = c("685.28", 
"1,055.67", "1,576.70", "4,423.02", "6,139.45")), row.names = 6:10, class = "data.frame")` when I use `dput(RTG[6:10, 1:5] )` .

Comment: By the way, I am so sorry if I don't give appropriate answers to your questions, I'm learning R for a month.

Comment: This works fine: `RTG$Total..MWh. <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "", RTG$Total..MWh., fixed = TRUE))`

Comment: @zx8754 thank you so much!

Comment: Here a little bit more to know: difference between setting decimal places  and formatting.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443687/formatting-decimal-places-in-r/12135122#12135122