# Is there a way to force rounded numbers such as 0 and 1 to 2 decimal places in tidyverse in R?

Tags: r

Currently, I have a data frame with values rounded to 2 decimal places. However, numbers such as 0, 0.5, and 1 are not reported how I need them (0.00, 0.50, 1.00). I'm working in tidyverse, and my current line of code for rounding is `mutate_at(vars(-N), funs(round(., 2)))` , which works aside from the problem mentioned above. When I try `mutate_at(vars(-N), funs(round(., 2), nsmall = 2)))` I'm given an error.

Comment: Hi, does [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443687/formatting-decimal-places-in-r) answer your question?

Comment: I actually looked at this thread and tried the suggestions before posting this. That's what gave me an error.

Comment: @WilliamHutson Please include sample data and expected output, including any errors you've encoutered; "gave me an error" is not telling us much ;-)

Comment: I have a few columns of confidence intervals and other variables in a data frame (e.g., 0.000, 1.000, 0.5678, etc.) and the first block of code in my post will round them to 0, 1, and 0.57 respectively. I need the result to be 0.00, 1.00, and 0.57. Running the second block of code 'mutate_at(vars(-N), funs(round(., 2), nsmall = 2)))' gives the error: Error in call2(): ! Can't create call to non-callable object

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `num`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(across(-N, num, digits = 2))
```

**Output**

```
      a     b N
1  0.50 17.52 a
2  1.00 20.58 b
3  2.00 17.47 c
4  7.98 16.56 d
5  5.99 21.11 e
6  7.50 23.48 f
7  4.78 17.11 g
8  9.20 18.77 h
9  4.59 21.39 i
10 6.46 18.89 j
```

However, it really depends if you need the result in a particular format or if you are just needing to display the result with the 2 decimals. For example, if you don't mind the data being in character, then you can use `sprintf`.

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(-N, ~ sprintf("%.2f",round(.x, 2))))
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(0.5, 1, 2, 7.97630587033927, 5.99083143589087, 
7.4982464578934, 4.78181807184592, 9.20062652369961, 4.59063704661094, 
6.46314722881652), b = c(17.522836093558, 20.5758226248436, 17.4732198179699, 
16.5616007035132, 21.1130455101375, 23.4848396719899, 17.1091119621415, 
18.7732864583377, 21.3871927985456, 18.8909927722998), N = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: This seemed to help, thank you! Do you know what I should do for a separate data frame without the column N that has categorical variable columns? Would I try mutate(across(num, digits = 2))?

Comment: @WilliamHutson Are you wanting to apply to only numeric columns or all columns?

Comment: only numeric on this second data frame.

Comment: @WilliamHutson You can use `is.numeric`. So, `mutate(across(where(is.numeric), num, digits = 2))`