# How to format # of decimal places in character vector in R

Tags: r, vector

Is it possible to change the decimal places to 2 in the following character vector in R?

Vector

```
x = c("0.857138", "1", "0.5", "not limiting", "0.1", "0.233333333333333", 
      "1", "0.333333333333333", "1", "1", "0.1", "0.65", "1", "1", 
      "0.6", "0.25", "1", "1", "0.25", "0.6", "1", "1", "0.6")
```

Comment: Do you need to keep the `"not limiting"` value?

Comment: @JayBee, yes I would need to keep "not limiting".

Answer (score 1):

Based on the StackOverflow thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443687/formatting-decimal-places-in-r?rq=2), you can get your desired output using `format(round(as.numeric(x), 2), nsmall = 2)`, which returns the following result:

```
 [1] "0.86" "1.00" "0.50" "  NA" "0.10" "0.23" "1.00" "0.33" "1.00" "1.00" "0.10"
[12] "0.65" "1.00" "1.00" "0.60" "0.25" "1.00" "1.00" "0.25" "0.60" "1.00" "1.00"
[23] "0.60"
```

Note that the output is still a character vector because the input was a character vector, so you can't do arithmetic with this. I had to coerce your vector `x` to a numeric format with `as.numeric()`, which forces your value of "not limiting" to "NA" because it's not coerceable to a number. As @JayBee said, if you do not need to keep this value, it'll allow you to start with a numeric vector rather than a character vector.