# R's Format function returning an odd result

Tags: r, integer, format, precision

Why does

```
format(4444444444444444444,scientific=FALSE)
```

return "4444444444444444672"?

I thought it might be an integer precision thing, but this number is relatively small. Thanks!

I'm running R version 3.0.0 on Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you give R an integer greater than:

```
> .Machine$integer.max
[1] 2147483647
```

It converts it to a double. The [R-FAQ has 7.31](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f). Questions related to floating point accuracy occur commonly on SO: [Controlling number of decimal digits in print output in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287616/controlling-digits-in-r)

(The size of vector indices was increased with the last version of R (3.0.0) and it seems possible that the max size for an integer may be widened in the future. I don't quite understand how we can keep the limit on sizes of integers and also access vector indices that are larger.)

Answer (score 4):

That's not a 32-bit integer.

```
R> as.integer(4444444444444444444)
[1] NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

It's a double-precision floating point number, which only have 15-16 places of precision.  The above fails because the number is greater than `.Machine$integer.max`.  The `...672` is rounding error.  If you need to use large numbers, consider packages like [gmp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmp/index.html).