# sum with n decimal places R

Tags: r

I am trying to have sum of two values in R with 6 decimal places but it only returns with 5.

```
85.85+0.01302778
# [1] 85.86303
```

I tried

```
round(85.85+0.01302778,6)
```

but it does not work.

Actually `sum(85.85,0.01302778)` gives only 5 decimals and I did not find any scope of decimal places in `?sum`.

Any suggestions

Comment: See [Controlling digits in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287616/controlling-digits-in-r) -- it is how the object is printed. try `print(85.85+0.01302778, digits = 10)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to get 6 digits:

```
> options(digits=8)
> 85.85+0.01302778
[1] 85.863028
```