# how to keep the same precision of float numbers in R, after reading from JSON file into R

Tags: json, r, floating-point-precision

I am new to R, I am currently reading some float numbers of high precision from JSON format file into R.
the command i am using to read the JSON file is :

```
json_data <- fromJSON(paste(readLines("file_name.json"), collapse=""))
```

the precision in  JSON file is 9.0114910478323 but in R it becomes 9.011491, i need the it in this form 9.0114910478323.

Comment: What you see is not necessarily what is stored.  Try `options()$digits)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Controlling digits in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287616/controlling-digits-in-r)

Comment: Actually  I thought may be it is from json reader, but it seems it works as I fix the options, thanks