# Can I change significant figures on the fly

Tags: javascript, r, rstudio

I'm using DT in RStudio which "provides an R interface to the JavaScript library DataTables".
Is there a way to change the **number of significant figures** displayed in the columns in DT?

Comment: `signif` might help. This link also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287616/controlling-digits-in-r