# Building custom print function, digits argument causes error

Tags: r

I am simply trying to limit the decimals for my output. But the `digits` argument is giving me trouble.

My code

```
#' @export
print.xts <- function(x) {
  print(x, digits = 5)

}
```

Gives the error when printing an `xts` object

```
Error in print.xts(x, digits = 5) : unused argument (digits = 5)
```

What can be the issue?

Comment: Have you tried `options()`?

Comment: Maybe it's because there's already a `print.xts` when you load the "xts" package. Have you tried giving "x" a different class and renaming your `print.xts` to whatever that class is?

Comment: Ahh, smart @AnandaMahto. That shold be it. So basically I was referencing in a loop...But shouldn't my print.xts override the print.xts in the xts package?

Comment: Can't you use `digits` with the default `print.xts` method?

Comment: Is there a way to set the digits option for xts print.xts? I found it at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287616/controlling-number-of-decimal-digits-in-print-output-in-r

Comment: @uncool, `print(sample.xts, digits = 2)` gives me the results with 2 digits ("sample.xts" comes from the help page for `xts`).

Comment: Yes. Thank you @AnandaMahto. What I essentially was trying to do was to override the print.xts function. But I've gone with the solution to change the options(digits = ) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There already exists a `print.xts` method in the `xts` package, try renaming the function which should work.