# How to find the relative frequency/Pie Chart after loading data?

Tags: r, csv, frequency

Ok so I am imported the CSV file where I had all of my data.

The csv contained the following data. This was all in the excel spread sheet. It will be easy to understand.

```
     SocialIssue Frequency   RelFreq
1        Housing       245 0.2401961
2 Transportation       112 0.1098039
3    Health Care       153 0.1500000
4      Education        71 0.0696078
5           Food       133 0.1303922
6          Other       306 0.3000000
```

My "R" code. Here i just import the file and load the data. The data loads perfectly. But I don't know how to find the relative frequency from this. 
This is what i have so far.

```
data1 <- read.csv("C:/Users/jaina/Desktop/Question1CSV.csv", header = T)
table(data1$SocialIssue)/sum(data1$Frequency)
```

Now the above code turns out to be something like this:

```
 Education  Food    Health Care    Housing     Other Transportation 
 0.001     0.001    0.001          0.001       0.001 0.001
```

The relative frequency is obviously not right but that's all i can think of..Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE** 
i ALSO want to create the pie chart of **Social Issue vs RelRreq**, now when i try this:

```
data1 <- read.csv("C:/Users/jaina/Desktop/Question1CSV.csv", header = T)
data1$RelFreq = data1$Frequency / sum(data1$Frequency)
options(digits = 6)

pie(data1)
```

It gives me the following error.

**Error in pie(data1) : 'x' values must be positive**

Comment: `table()` would be used to create the table you imported. Like if you had a bunch of rows that said `Housing` `table()` would count them up to 245 like you already have. Sounds like you just want something like `data1$RelFreq = data1$Frequency / sum(data1$Frequency)`

Comment: Works..that is exactly what i wanted but is there any way i can keep the full answer and not the 2 digit answer.

Comment: [How to control the number of digits printed in R](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2287616/903061)