# R displays 1-really small number as 1. How can I access its actual value?

Tags: r, r-plotly

If I enter the following in to the console of R:

```
1 - 3.125e-09
```

It prints `1` as its result.

However, a logical test will show that it is not actually `1`.

```
if ( (1-3.125e-09) == 1){
   print('Number is equal to one')
} else {
   print('Number is not one')
}
```

How is this happening? How can I capture the true value? This behavior appears to break some graphing library functions where the total value should add up to 1.

Comment: `print(1 - 3.125e-09, digits=20)` will print the accurate value.  This is just a display issue.  How is it breaking some graphing library?

Comment: Set the default number of digits with, for example, `options(digits=15)`; see https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/options.html for more details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Controlling number of decimal digits in print output in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287616/controlling-number-of-decimal-digits-in-print-output-in-r)

Comment: The print values not the issue.

To clarify - its a donut chart. The values need to add up to one. If the value is really small, when I got to calculate the delta (1-small number) the value would print as 1 yes, but its true value is really small. However, when plotly tries to add that trace, it first draws the really small trace, but it cant add the second trace - as it thinks its value is 1. So there is no space for it. I can get around this by doing a quick check - just wondering is there a way to force accessing the true value.

Comment: Try to create a reproducible example using `plotly` and add that to your question please. Otherwise this is likely to get closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @KevinBolger:  That sounds like a bug in `plotly`.  You should report it to the developers of that package.