# How to round numbers in a vector to only show necessary decimals in R?

Tags: r, vector, decimal, rounding

I have a vector that contains both integers and numbers with decimal places. I want to only display decimal places as necessary. For example, I have the following vector:

```
vec <- c(0.01, 0.1, 1, 10)
```

R currently displays the values as such:

```
> vec
[1]  0.01  0.10  1.00 10.00
```

The output I'm looking for would be this:

```
0.01  0.1  1  10
```

Thus far, I've only been able to round all values of the vector to the same decimal place. Thanks!

Comment: `as.character(vec)` returns `"0.01" "0.1"  "1"    "10"`. This turns your `numeric` vector into a `character` vector (which I assume is fine since you're asking after output formatting). Is this what you're after?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287616/controlling-number-of-decimal-digits-in-print-output-in-r) might be of interest.

Comment: Other options might be: `formatC(vec)` or `prettyNum(vec)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may use an extra S3 class:

```
print.myNumeric <- function(x) cat(x, sep = "  ")
```

Compare printing before and after adding the class:

```
vec
#> [1]  0.01  0.10  1.00 10.00

class(vec) <- c("myNumeric", class(vec))

vec
#> 0.01  0.1  1  10
```

Basic math preserves the class and the printing:

```
4 * vec + 1:4
#> 1.04  2.4  7  44
```