# decimal in MySQL to R

Tags: mysql, r

```r
library(RMySQL)
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), dbname="hs***", host="localhost",
                 port = 3306, user="****",
                 password="****")
dbSendQuery(con, "SEt NAMES euckr")
d <- dbReadTable(con, "accidents")
str(d)

#it results :
$ lat        : num  38 38 38 38 38 38 37 38 38 35 ...
$ longt      : num  127 127 127 127 127 ...
```

structure of latitude and longitude in R says num, but I made these columns decimal(9,7) and (11,8) in MYSQL.

I want to know how to fix it.

Also, I got these error codes:

```
1: In .local(conn, statement, ...) :
  Decimal MySQL column 14 imported as numeric
2: In .local(conn, statement, ...) :
  Decimal MySQL column 15 imported as numeric
```

Comment: how about `dbGetQuery(conn, "select * from accidents")`

Comment: I did that.. but I got almost same results :  $ lat        : num  37.6 37.6 37.6 37.6 37.6 ...
 $ longt      : num  127 127 127 127 127 ...

Comment: To complement the coment @CatalystRPA: have you tried casting to character within the select and then convert it to double once the data is in R?

Comment: also have to tried to convert the data to double in R to make sure numeric is not just rounding the results for displaying (possibly there are many digits behind the comma)

Comment: @DPH oh, yes! It has many digits behind the comma because it is information of lattitude and longitude. Then, should I try to convert data in R into double?

Comment: you can try to subtract 37 from $lat to see if the data got read in correctly ... just tried a few things here an R rounds doubles also for display depending but one I subtract the value in front of the comma/dot I get a number smaller than 1

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this sequence as it might be the solution to your problem - R seems to round values for displaying:

```r
y <- "1.1000000001"
y
[1] "1.1000000001"

y1 <- as.double(y)
y1
[1] 1.1


y2 <- y1-1
y2-0.1
[1] 1.000001e-10
```

Comment: Is that mean R round values just for "displaying" and raw data doesn't change?

Comment: I tried as.double(d$latitude) and as.double(d$longitude) in R  -> I got raw data latitude and longitude that I want to get. However, when I try str(d) in R -> It still says it is numeric..

Comment: IIRC numeric can be double and integer depending on what you supply to it - and from what my sequence show the data is beeing rounded for display reasons... I just tried my sequence with as.numeric() instead of as.double and it works also

Comment: From the manual: "double is identical to numeric.... R has no single precision data type. All real numbers are stored in double precision format. "

Comment: Related post about print method, R is not rounding it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2287616/680068

Comment: @zx8754 I am sorry to not express myself correctly: I meant that R rounds the data when printing (and now thx to you I now how to increase the quantity of digits after the point/comma)

Comment: @DPH no worries, we have all been there :)