# Set the decimal place rounding for R to a specific default

Tags: r, rounding, default

I want to set the decimal place rounding for RStudio to a specific default.

For example, I want all numbers in my output for a given script to be rounded to 12 decimal places.

Here are my questions:
-Is this even possible?
-Can I use 1 line of code from the beginning of my script to accomplish this task?
-Do I have to repeat this over and over again to accomplish this task?
-Is there any other method to accomplish this task.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps this will help? [Controlling the Number of Decimal Digits in Print Output in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287616/controlling-number-of-decimal-digits-in-print-output-in-r)

Comment: That let to a method that seemed to be useful. Unfortunately, the issue I have is with the data itself, not the coding. But this link helped illuminate the problem.