# Extracting exact value from a data.frame in R

Tags: r

I can not find the answer to this question. All the answers my search engine gives me is how to round the number instead of how to get an unrounded number. Suppose I have a data.frame:

```
a <- c(1:4)
b <- c(1.123456789, 2.123456789, 3.123456789, 4.123456789)
df <- data.frame(a, b)
```

All methods I know return me a rounded number to the 6th digit after point:

```
df[2,2]
# [1] 2.123457
df[2,]
#   a        b
# 2 2 2.123457
df$b
# [1] 1.123457 2.123457 3.123457 4.123457
df$b[2]
# [1] 2.123457
df[df$a == 2, ]
#   a        b
# 2 2 2.123457
```

So, how **to get the exact value**? My desired output would be

```
[1] 2.123456789
```

Thank you!

Comment: Use `print` with digits `print(df[2, 2], digits = 16)#
[1] 2.123456789`

Comment: Thank you! It works!!! I totally forgot this possibility.

Comment: `how to get the exact value` ... you are using floating point values which by definition are not exact.

Comment: Note that there is a difference between how a number is *stored* and how it is *printed* on the console. For instance, see `pi`; now set `options(digits=19)` and then see `pi` again. The stored value never changed, just what is shown on the console. Another related option is `scipen=`; I encourage you to explore [`?options`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/options.html) to see the description of it and others. A key difference between `print(., digits=16)` and `options(digits=16)` is that the latter affects everything, not just the one call to `print` (until reset).

Comment: Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/2287616/15293191

Comment: Thank you all for the profound comments! In practice I was needed to get only a single value which I was not able to see by `View(df)`

Comment: `df[2,2]` gives you the precise number. From there, it's `digits=` in whichever form. Is that it?

Comment: You can also use `dput(df[2, 2])`.