# How to add magnitudes in R?

Tags: r

I have values of the magnitude of e-11 (representing light) and I would like to bring them into [nm]. I figured out that, e.g.

```
df$w.length[1]
[1] 1.239842e-11

df$w.length[1] + 1e-11
[1] 2.239842e-11
```

works but

```
> df$w.length[1] + 1e9
[1] 1e+09
```

doesn't. Also simply

```
> 1e-12 + 1e9
[1] 1e+09
```

not as well. Why is that?

Comment: [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) and [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal) and [Controlling the number of digits in print output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287616/controlling-number-of-decimal-digits-in-print-output-in-r)

Comment: `1e-12` is a vanishingly small number.  `1e+09` is an enormous number.  Adding them together basically gives you `1e+09` plus some noise.  It's ~ `1,000,000,000.0000000000001`.  Which gets displayed as 1e9 due to rounding.

Comment: It's also falling foul of floating point issues as displayed in @RuiBarradas link - you can demonstrate this by doing `1e+09 == (1e+09 + 1e-12)` which evaluates as `TRUE`.  A more useful question would be this - you are converting from one unit to another - what it the first unit?

Comment: Well, thanks, I'm trying to get a hold of this..  @PaulStaffordAllen I simply want to express e-11 in e^-9. The latter would be nanometers while the first would be 10-something in picometers. The unit is meters (for the wavelength).

Comment: But then there's an error in your question, `1.239842e-11 + 1e-9` is not the same as `1e-9`. In the question you have a difference in orders of magnitude of 20.

Comment: But isn't 1e-12 +1e9 = 1e-3? Hope that's not too dumb.. ah, wait, that's for division...   well, true. How do I express 1e-11 in nm then?

Comment: 1e-12 * 1e-9 = 1e-3.  Multiplying the numbers can be shown by adding or subtracting the exponents. Adding or subtracting the entire number is not the same.

Comment: Yeah, sorry,.. it's a while that I used to do this.. I guess I simply have to mulitply by 100 to express numbers of 1e-11 in terms of 1e-9, right?