# how to avoid rounding off the numbers when inputting the files

Tags: r, dataframe, rounding, read.table

I have two files and I am checking its correlation.
But while inputing the files it round off the value or keep the number till 5 digit after decimal.
I want to keep all the digits and not let R round it off.

```
expr = read.table(file = "residuals_expression.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\t" )


GTEX-111CU  GTEX-111CU  0.1666530378417794
```

Its rounding it to `0.1666530`

Is there any way to prevent this round off?
Thank you.

Comment: It's probably not rounding at all, but is only printing a certain number of digits. You can [see this FAQ to adjust how many decimal places print](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2287616/903061).

Comment: thank you, I will have a look at it.